# How do you instruct Blender via .mtl file to import vertex colors?

Tags: materials, objects, color, vertex-colors, obj

I have a .OBJ file with vertex colors like:

```
g Model
o Cubo.005
mtllib temp.mtl
usemtl 12212233866733520400
v 28.0000 -4.0000 -66.0000 0.007 0.039 0.560
v 28.0000 -4.0000 -65.0000 0.007 0.039 0.560
v 28.0000 -3.0000 -65.0000 0.007 0.039 0.560
...
```

and a .MTL file with

```
newmtl 12212233866733520400
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Tr 1.000000
illum 1
Ns 0.000000
map_Kd temp12212233866733520400.png
```

Here `map_Kd` references a PNG texture which when the .OBJ is imported results in:

[image]

I can confirm that the vertex colors are there inside the *Color Attributes* tab within the Object Data Properties section, but they are not used in the defined material. How do I edit the .MTL so the material will reference those vertex colors after importing? Currently I have to manually replace the Texture Node with the *Color Attribute* node.

[image]

I tried removing the line `map_Kd temp12212233866733520400.png` but then nothing is plugged into the BSDF when importing the obj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. OBJ vertex colors have no effect on MTLs or materials.

Comment: i feared that was the case. well that means i will just write a python script that will create my needed setup after object import. thank you!